# Compile separate files

Tags: python, biopython

In the case to have three files:

```
File1
    >TAIR:175_a
     ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF
    >TAIR:175_b
     ZZZLAALSKDJFALKSDJFL;KJEIURALKDJFNVALKSDJFKZZZ
    >TAIR:175_c
     ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF

File2
    >TAIR:674_a
     ASLALKSDGHLA;KSJDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA
    >TAIR:674_b
     ASLALKSDGHDJGDGSDDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA

File3
    >TAIR:812_a
     KLJALSKDHGLAKSDHJFIEUROWASDLKGNIEASDFJKWERLJKJ
    >TAIR:812_c
     ASLALKSDGHLA;KSJDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA

File4
    >TAIR:975_b
     KLJALSKDHGLAKSDHJFIEUROWASDLKGNIEASDFJKWERLJKJ

File5
    >TAIR:444_b
     QQALKSDJFWOIAOQIWUERTOIUQTOIUOQIWEURLASKDJFA
    >TAIR:444_c
     QQALKSDJFWOIAOQIWUERTOIUQTOIUOQIWEURLASKDJFA
```

I wrote this code to extract the name of all sequences in the directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Bio import SeqIO
filenames = ["file1","file2","file3"]
ids = []

for record in filenames:
    f = SeqIO.parse(record, 'fasta')
    ids.append(f.id)

print ids
```

And the output is this:

```
 python search_list.py 
[<generator object parse at 0x7f32836018c0>, <generator object parse at 0x7f3283601910>, <generator object parse at 0x7f3283601960>]
```

And the output that I expect is:

```
file_a
    >TAIR:175_a
     ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF
    >TAIR:674_a
     ASLALKSDGHLA;KSJDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA

file_b
    >TAIR:175_b
     ZZZLAALSKDJFALKSDJFL;KJEIURALKDJFNVALKSDJFKZZZ
    >TAIR:674_b
     ASLALKSDGHDJGDGSDDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA
    >TAIR:975_b
     KLJALSKDHGLAKSDHJFIEUROWASDLKGNIEASDFJKWERLJKJ
    >TAIR:444_b
     QQALKSDJFWOIAOQIWUERTOIUQTOIUOQIWEURLASKDJFA

file_c
    >TAIR:175_c
     ALSKDJFLKAHGLKASJDFLAKJSDLKGHALKSDHGALKALKSJDF
    >TAIR:812_c
     ASLALKSDGHLA;KSJDFIEURALKSDHGLANVALKSDJGHKLJA
    >TAIR:444_c
     QQALKSDJFWOIAOQIWUERTOIUQTOIUOQIWEURLASKDJFA
```

Any suggestion to solve this opening the files in the list "ids" and compile them?

Comment: try using `f = list(SeqIO.parse(record,'fasta')`, at least it won't print that you have generators but may guide you a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Ignoring the print parentheses issue,) Your code breaks on my system (Python 3.6.0; Biopython 1.69) with:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'id'
```

as `SeqIO.parse()` returns a generator.  Also your "output that I expect" is completely wrong.  What you're expecting, given this code, is:

```
['TAIR:175_a', 'TAIR:674_a', 'TAIR:812_a', 'TAIR:975_b', 'TAIR:175_b', 'TAIR:444_b', 'TAIR:175_c', 'TAIR:444_c']
```

And in my environment, the following code will get it for you:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

filenames = ["file1.fasta", "file2.fasta", "file3.fasta"]

ids = []

for filename in filenames:
    records = SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta')

    for record in records:
        ids.append(record.id)

print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that output because you're asking python to print an object, so it is just printing the memory address by default instead of the contents.
You might be better off just using the standard python open method (iterate through the list of files you want to examine). You can then iterate through each line in the file and add it to a list or whatever you like. Let me know if an example would be helpful.